# Any tool to parse a ZF project for translate() method?

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization

I used gettext as adapter for Zend_Translate in the past and poedit has such utility that parses a project for translate() methods.

But I'm not using gettext anymore (it's a requirement) and I use CSV instead.

I'd like to know if there are any utilities to parse my project and help me to gather all my translated string.

I know some such as Navigation, Form, and Routes won't included as it is done slightly differently but if it could be a least in views script, It would help me a lot !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/), which produces `.po` file, which is a regular text file, which you can easily parse to generate CSV.

The other way is to log untranslated messages directly to CSV, like described here:

- [Proper handling of untranslated messages - Blacksheep's Paradise](http://www.thomasweidner.com/flatpress/2009/02/)
- [How to add missing translations  - Blacksheep's Paradise](http://www.thomasweidner.com/flatpress/2010/07/30/how-to-add-missing-translations/)

Answer (score 1):

No experience with this in particular, but it looks like it might be of use to you:
http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/csv2po